# Error 800A0401 while running VB script?

Tags: vbscript, diskspace

I want to check disk space of another windows remote server from my windows server.

While googling for it, I found the following code [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/51f3ad3f-cfc3-4793-b83a-cc7e852084c2/drive-space-on-remote-server) (add Reference: System.Management dll):

```
using System.Management;
private void CalculateFreeUsed(string srvname)
{
    try
    {
        // Connection credentials to the remote computer, not needed if the logged account has access
        ConnectionOptions oConn = new ConnectionOptions();
        srvname=192.168.238.77 // take it default for testing
        oConn.Username = "MatinXie";
        oConn.Password = "acd";
        string strNameSpace = @"\\";

        if (srvname != "")
            strNameSpace += srvname;
        else
            strNameSpace += ".";

        strNameSpace += @"\root\cimv2";

        ManagementScope oMs = new ManagementScope(strNameSpace, oConn);

        //get Fixed disk state

        ObjectQuery oQuery = new ObjectQuery("select FreeSpace,Size,Name from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType=3");

        //Execute the query
        ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oMs, oQuery);

        //Get the results
        ManagementObjectCollection oReturnCollection = oSearcher.Get();

        //loop through found drives and write out info
        double D_Freespace = 0;
        double D_Totalspace = 0;
        foreach (ManagementObject oReturn in oReturnCollection)
        {
            // Disk name
            MessageBox.Show("Name : " + oReturn["Name"].ToString());
            // Free Space in bytes
            string strFreespace = oReturn["FreeSpace"].ToString();
            D_Freespace = D_Freespace + System.Convert.ToDouble(strFreespace);
            // Size in bytes
            string strTotalspace = oReturn["Size"].ToString();
            D_Totalspace = D_Totalspace + System.Convert.ToDouble(strTotalspace);
        }
    }


    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to obtain Server Information. The node you are trying to scan can be a Filer or a node which you don't have administrative priviledges. Please use the UNC convention to scan the shared folder in the server", "Server Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Now I don't know how to run it. How to add main function here. But, when I double click this script I get error 800A0401. 
Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to run a C# code in vb.net

Comment: @Sky then how to run it, I don't have any idea of either

Comment: Start by reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391854/how-to-start-programming-from-scratch) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-01.aspx)

Comment: And probably you should start all the way from scratch for a programming language before trying to do advanced stuffs.

Comment: Do you want to use VBScript or VB.net? They're two different languages.

Comment: Anything will  be fine, I just want to find disk capacity on other server. Another thing I thought is to write a batch script on another server and run it through my pc to get the disk size, but I stuck in errors given at http://superuser.com/questions/767342/how-to-run-batch-script-on-server-which-exists-in-different-domain-of-your-pc

Answer (score 0):

Error 800a0401 translates to "Expected End of Statement". You're getting this error, because your code is VB.net, but you're trying to run it in the VBScript interpreter.

Querying the disk information from remote computers via VBScript can be done like this:

```
computer = "192.168.238.77"

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://" & computer & "/root/cimv2")

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3"
For Each disk In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  WScript.Echo disk.Name & vbTab & disk.Size & vbTab & disk.FreeSpace
Next
```

For this to work the account running the script must have local admin privileges on the remote host. Otherwise you need to provide credentials for an account that does have the required privileges, which makes the code slightly more complicated (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for further details):

```
computer = "192.168.238.77"
username = "DOMAIN\user"
password = "pass"

Set locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set wmi = locator.ConnectServer(computer, "root\cimv2", username, password)
wmi.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3"
For Each disk In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  WScript.Echo disk.Name & vbTab & disk.Size & vbTab & disk.FreeSpace
Next
```